# MySQL NATURAL JOIN 3 tables related to a parent table with a contraint on the parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, natural-join

I have 3 child tables that are related to a parent table with the following schema:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(model, price, ...)
Laptop(model, price, ...)
Printer(model, price, ...)
```

The `Product` table is the parent table of `PC`, `Laptop`, and `Printer`.
The three child tables have a foreign key `model` that reference the `Prodcut` table.
Also, PC, Laptop, and Printer don't have identical schemas.

I want to find out the best way to `SELECT` the model and price of all the products(pc, laptop, and printer) that are made by a certain maker.

I'm new to SQL and my  intuition right now tells me that I should join the parent table to each of the child tables, filter the results, and then perform a union. The query appears to return the correct result.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT model, price FROM Product NATURAL JOIN PC WHERE maker = 'B' UNION 
SELECT model, price FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Laptop WHERE maker = 'B' UNION 
SELECT model, price FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Printer WHERE maker = 'B';
```

Is this an effective way to query for my information? I feel like I'm typing way too much and repeating much of the same constraints to achieve my result.

Is there a better query I could write?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to increase the efiiciency use UNION ALL rather than UNION (or UNION DISTINCT)

```
SELECT model, price FROM Product NATURAL JOIN PC WHERE maker = 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT model, price FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Laptop WHERE maker = 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT model, price FROM Product NATURAL JOIN Printer WHERE maker = 'B';
```

The difference in execution speed comes from the fact UNION requires internal temporary table with index (to skip duplicate rows) while UNION ALL will create table without such index.

Even to know more, please go through the article
http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the MySql but something like this?

```
SELECT model, price 
FROM Product 
JOIN PC 
ON PC.model = Product.model
JOIN Laptop
ON Laptop.model = Product.Model
JOIN Printer 
ON Printer.model = Product.model
WHERE Product.maker = 'B'
```

Edit 1:
Try this:

```
SELECT p.model, p.price 
FROM Product p
JOIN PC pc
ON pc.model = p.model
JOIN Laptop lp
ON lp.model = p.Model
JOIN Printer pr
ON pr.model = p.model
WHERE p.maker = 'B'
```

Comment: It gave me error: ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'price' in field list is ambiguous. I ended up qualifying the SELECT columns with a table and that worked, but it resulted in an empty set. I'm thinking that it's the way it gets evaluated. I ran this query to test it out `SELECT Product.model FROM Product JOIN PC ON PC.model = Product.model JOIN Laptop ON Laptop.model = Product.model` and this returned an empty set. I believe since PC and Laptop dont share any models then it should return an empty set.

Comment: price is not present in product table that's why it has ambiguous error.